# How to call a function from an object, from within an other function's function of the same object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've an object, which simplified a bit looks like:

```
function obj(arg){
    return{
        fct1: function(){
            $(".output").append("called fct1 with arg: "+arg+"<br>");
        },
        fct2: function(){
            $(".output").append("called fct2, which has an other function, which calls fct1<br>");
            fct2a();
            function fct2a(){
                $(".output").append("doing something else, then calling fct1<br>");
                this.fct1(); //not within scope
            }
        }
        }
    }
var myobj = obj("asd");
myobj.fct2();
```

I want to call fct1 from fct2a, how? [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jt2x7mjs/13/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a temp var and asign `this` object to that var and call from that. Please find the code below

```
function obj(arg){
    return{
        var temp=this;
        fct1: function(){
            $(".output").append("called fct1 with arg: "+arg+"<br>");
        },
        fct2: function(){
            $(".output").append("called fct2, which has an other function, which calls fct1<br>");
            fct2a();
            function fct2a(){
                $(".output").append("doing something else, then calling fct1<br>");
                temp.fct1(); 
            }
        }
        }
    }
var myobj = obj("asd");
myobj.fct2();
```

Comment: Works if I declare var temp before calling fct2a(). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare `fct1()` separately and invoke it where you need it:

```
function obj(arg){
    function innerFct1(arg) {
        $(".output").append("called fct1 with arg: "+arg+"<br>");
    }
    return{
        fct1: innerFct1,
        fct2: function(){
            $(".output").append("called fct2, which has an other function, which calls fct1<br>");
            fct2a();
            function fct2a(){
                $(".output").append("doing something else, then calling fct1<br>");
                innerFct1("arg2"); //not within scope
            }
        }
    }
}
var myobj = obj("asd");
myobj.fct2();
```

Comment: what if innerFct1 takes in an arg?